# How can I use wx.GenericMessageDialog?

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

Would anyone please help me understand how to use **"wx.GenericMessageDialog.**init**"** properly so that it will appear as an another frame?

I have a main frame and I would like to be able to change `msg1` from the main frame.

```py
class AnotherFrame(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, msg1):

        wx.GenericMessageDialog.__init__(self, None, msg1, caption="title",style=wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to have a generic message dialog behave like a frame. Here is a typical implementation:

```
with wx.GenericMessageDialog(self, "message", "caption", style=wx.YES_NO | wx.ICON_QUESTION) as dialog:
    dialog.ShowModal()
```

If you don't want it to be modal I would suggest subclassing `wx.Dialog` and calling `dialog.Show()` instead of `dialog.ShowModal()`

Comment: There is also `wx.lib.messagepanel` that will let you put a panel that is similar to a `wx.MessageDialog` into a frame.